# I want to follow the path of drawing dynamic curve,how to solve it?

Tags: android

1、Here is the chart:
[image]

2、Here is the code:

```
private void drawCircle( Canvas canvas, String content ){
    mPath.addCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mRadius, Direction.CCW);
    canvas.rotate(180, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(content, mPath, 0, 0, mPaint);
}
```

3、My problem is how to let the circle one point one point display，Not all one-time display。I'm try to use Handler/Thread/Timer to draw a dynamic chart by drawTextOnPath and drawPath method, but there show nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "circle follow the exists circle, and it's dynamic drawing"??? Can you provide an example sketch of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I mean, let the circle one point one point display，Not all one-time display。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use postDelayed() and add a new character each time.

```
public class MyView extends View {

    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private float mRadius = 100;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private String theWholeText = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private String theCurrentText = "";
    private int i = 0;
    private long frequency = 150;
    private Runnable addCharacter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            theCurrentText = theWholeText.substring(0, ++i);
            invalidate();
        }
    };

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setTextSize(20);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, String content) {
        mPath.addCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mRadius, Path.Direction.CCW);
        canvas.rotate(180, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(content, mPath, 0, 0, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        drawCircle(canvas, theCurrentText);
        if (theCurrentText.length() < theWholeText.length())
            postDelayed(addCharacter, frequency);
    }
}
```

Please mark as correct answer if that works out for you!